# Creating a datetime object in a particular timezone in JodaTime

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I have a date, timezone and time as Strings, and I want to construct a JodaTime object with that date and time for that timezone. The code I have written is

```
String dateString = "2016-06-02";
String time = "01:00:00";
String timezone = "Australia/Brisbane";
DateTime dateInTimezone = DateTime.parse(dateString+" "+time,DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
            .withZone(DateTimeZone.forID(timezone));
```

I would expect `dateInTimezone` to be created with value `2016-06-02T01:00:00.000+10:00` but it gets created with value `2016-06-02T18:00:00.000+10:00`. My systems timezone is in `America\Los_Angeles`. From what I understand it takes the time I pass as a parameter in my systems timezone and converts that to the timezone I specify. Probably thats why `01:00:00` got internally converted to `18:00:00`.

How do I create a joda time object with specified time and specified timezone, without any conversions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the timezone to your formatter before parsing:

```
String dateString = "2016-06-02";
String time = "01:00:00";
String timezone = "Australia/Brisbane";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
        .withZone(DateTimeZone.forID(timezone));
DateTime dateInTimezone = DateTime.parse(dateString+" "+time, formatter);
```

Another option is to do it your way, but call [`DateTime.withZoneRetainFields()`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withZoneRetainFields(org.joda.time.DateTimeZone)), but then there's the risk of the parse failing if it falls out on an invalid date (e.g. between a DST gap) in the initial timezone.